# Equal size Gradiant for each colors used in LinearGradientPaint - Java2D

Tags: java, java-2d

I use the following settings to paint the gradients,

```
final float[] FRACTIONS = { 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.50f, 0.75f };
final Color[] DARK_COLORS = { Color.YELLOW.darker(),
   Color.pink, Color.BLUE.darker(), Color.GREEN.darker() };
```

I am using the LinearGradientPaint Class from JDK.

and i get the following result

[image: Non Equal sizes Gradiant]

**actually i need each color use equal space in the gradients,
how can i achieve that ? somewhere i read that i must adjust the fraction.**

can anyone tell me , how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ending the colours at 0.75. Try for example:

```
final float[] FRACTIONS = { 0.0f, 0.33f, 0.67f, 1.0f };
```

Comment: i think this could be best final float[] FRACTIONS = { 0.25f, 0.50f, 0.75f, 1.0f }; update your answer and i will select it because you give me a hint, thanks.

Comment: @Mihir oddly enough I get the dark yellow with my fractions and your colours (I had a program at hand where I could directly paste it for testing). Maybe part of the gradient gets cut out in your case. Another thing is the definition of equal space; it's not definite what looks right and that may require visual adjusting.